# I can send variables from flash to javascript, but unable to do the opposite

Tags: javascript, flash

I have this in AS3

```
var myName:String = "David";
var result:Number = ExternalInterface.call("methodInJS", myName);
trace("Result from JS call is: "+result);
```

And in javascript

```
function methodInJS(name) {
alert("Hello to " + name);
 return 17;
}
```

This allows me to send to javascript. What is the method to do the opposite. I want to send to flash.

SOLUTION: Looks like the addCallback works.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you figured it out. You should write up the solution as an answer and then accept it as the answer for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to create an asynchronous call handler in Flex and then call that from JavaScript. See the docs here http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=passingarguments_4.html

Comment: im reading it and im not sure I understand. 

They are however using the externalinterface to execute javascript functions.